# How to skip the Debug Assertion Failed and break directly in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with some C++, and I had a typo in my code causing this. In the future I'd rather Visual Studio would break directly on the faulty code when running in DEBUG MODE directly from Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition), with the actual expression, rather than showing me this annoying prompt.

Is there a setting for this somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Start the program *in* the debugger instead of just running it?

Comment: This warning is usually equivalent to a segfault or a memory access violation.

Comment: press "Retry", confirm that you what to debug it, select respective instance of Visual Studio, anlyze code pointed by "Call stack", fix bug.

Comment: Alternative "Exceptions Settings" (Ctrl-Alt-E if I remember correctly), select other exceptions. Now VS will stop before exception is thrown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's what F5 does in Visual Studio... Yet the dialog appears regardless.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen out of curiosity, did my answer solve it or is it something else I can learn here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a setting for this somewhere?

You could do it programmaticaly by [*setting report mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode):

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

The required header is `<crtdbg.h>`.

Comment: I don't have MSVS on hand to try out what you suggested, but that sounds a lot like it will turn off stopping on the assert and allow the program to terminate rather than stopping to allow debugging without showing the unwanted dialog.

Comment: @user4581301 Perhaps then you should try it if your unsure, as what you're suggesting is not the case.